# Are metal face plates safe for metal gang boxes?

Tags: electrical, grounding

So if I understand household wiring correctly:

- The ground prong is meant to safely conduct stray current (shorts, etc) to the ground.
- All outlets and switches need to be grounded to the gang box.
- A Metal gang box itself must be grounded.

So if I put a metal plate on a metal gang box, and that gang box is receiving current through grounding, isn't it possible for myself to become the ground? Should I replace any metal face plates with plastic?

Comment: You'd be the ground if you were standing barefoot in the ground--but even then, you're still likely not the path of least resistance provided the circuit is properly grounded. Note, that this *can* be an issue if, for instance, you are barefoot in your basement.

Comment: If the box is properly grounded you are fine.